# How to Check XMPP calls in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmpp

when we are using inspector in Google chrome we can see all request that generating that browser window ,there we have option for viewing XHR request how to check XMPP requests from  chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can see each XMPP request in the Network tab of Google Chrome inspector as an XHR request with the name http-bind/ (I assume that you are connecting to the XMPP server with BOSH/HTTP-BIND).

Another way, using Strophe.js library, is to override rawOutput/rawInput functions in order to log all XMPP messages exchanged with the server.

See: http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.3/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.rawOutput